# Understanding Monte Carlo EM in a mixed effects model context

Tags: mixed-model, monte-carlo, expectation-maximization

I am currently reading [Mixed Effects Models for Complex Data](https://www.routledge.com/Mixed-Effects-Models-for-Complex-Data/Wu/p/book/9780367384913) by Lang Wu. On page 136, the author mentions the Monte Carlo EM algorithm as a way of treating missing covariate in the mixed effect model.

Say we have ($\mathbf{y}_i, \mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{b}_i$) as complete data for $i = 1,..., n$ where $\mathbf{b}_i$ are random effects and $\mathbf{z}_i = (\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}, \mathbf{z}_{obs,i}) $ are the vector of covariates corresponding to unobserved and observed elements.

The E-step is an expectation of the log likelihood, ie.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& Q_i(\boldsymbol{\theta}|\boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) = \iint \{\log f(\mathbf{y}_i|\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{b}_i, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2) + \log f(\mathbf{z}|\boldsymbol{\alpha}) + \log f(\mathbf{b}_i|D)\}  \\
 & f(\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}, \mathbf{b}_i|\mathbf{z}_{obs,i}, \mathbf{y}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)})d\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}d\mathbf{b}_i 
\end{split}
\end{equation} where $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2, D )$ are parameters associated with the density of Z, the mixed effect model and the random effect.

I understand the need to generate samples from $f(\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}, \mathbf{b}_i|\mathbf{z}_{obs,i}, \mathbf{y}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)})$. Book mention that this could be done by rejection sampling. The book mentions on 137 that since
\begin{equation}
f(\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}|\mathbf{z}_{obs,i}, \mathbf{b}_i, \mathbf{y}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) \propto f(\mathbf{z}_i|\boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) f(\mathbf{y}_i|\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{b}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)})
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
f( \mathbf{b}_i| \mathbf{z}_{mis,i},\mathbf{z}_{obs,i}, \mathbf{y}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) \propto f(\mathbf{b}_i|\boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) f(\mathbf{y}_i|\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{b}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)})
\end{equation}
then "we only need to generate samples from the right-hand sides which can be accomplished using rejection sampling methods since the density functions on the right-hand sides are all known".

My question is regarding the implementation details.

My understanding of it is that, we are not actually generating samples from the right-hand side, but we are actually using some proposal distribution which shares the same domain of $\mathbf{z}_{mis,i}, \mathbf{b}_i$ and then using uniform distribution U(0,1) to accept or reject?

- Say only one covariate is missing and that $z_{mis,i}$ is binary. Do I sample from a Bernoulli distribution, say $h(z)$? I understand that the target density function has to be bounded by h(z).
  I am not seeing how  $f(\mathbf{z}_i|\boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)}) f(\mathbf{y}_i|\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{b}_i, \boldsymbol{\theta}^{(t)})$ would be bounded by sampling from this proposed Bernoulli distribution
- We only accept both $z_{mis,i}, \mathbf{b}_i$ when they are BOTH accepted?
- I am trying to figure out the implementation details and would appreciate any advice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) If $z_{mis,i}$ is binary, there is no need to reject, direct sampling is available; (2) simulating from both conditionals is a Gibbs sampling round, hence does not produce an exact simulation from the joint distribution, unless repeated iterations are called.

Comment: (3) When simulating from the conditionals, each component of $z_{mis,i}, \mathbf{b}_i$ is accepted/rejected separately (4) it is correct to view the explanation of the right hand side as setting a target for which a specific accept-reject algorithm can be constructed.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you so much for taking the time to respond to my question. If I could seek clarification on (1) (and pardon my ignorance) : It's the first time I hear of  direct sampling means we use  $\epsilon$ such that $z_{i,mis} = F^{-1}(\epsilon)$ and this $\epsilon$ is evaluated from the right hand side of equation = 1 (ie. product of density = 1)? Thank you

Comment: I do not understand your question, sorry.